# Codeigniter join 2 tables data with new column for id value

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I'm new to `Codeigniter` and `PHP`, just learning. I've searched for this but couldn't find the right answer. I have a table that contain some data, lets call it `posts` and in this table, each post have a `category_id`. I have another table called `categories` and in this table I have 2 columns: `id` and `name`.

I want to join the two tables that the result I'll get is the same as `posts` with another column called `category_name` that will be taken from `categories.name`. Just can't figure out how to do so.

This is what I was up to so far:

```
function getPostsWithByCategoryID($numberOfRows, $start, $categoryId)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('posts')->order_by('id','desc')->limit($numberOfRows, $start);
    $this->db->where('category_id', $categoryID);
    $this->db->join('categories', 'posts.category_id == categories.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

========================================================================

EDIT:

After trying Adrian Forsius answer:

```
function getPostsWithByCategoryID($numberOfRows, $start, $categoryId)
{
    $this->db->select('*, category.name AS category_name');
    $this->db->from('posts')->order_by('id','desc')->limit($numberOfRows, $start);
    $this->db->where('category_id', $categoryID);
    $this->db->join('categories', 'posts.category_id = categories.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error Number: 1054: Unknown column 'category.name' in 'field list'
SELECT *, `category`.`name` AS category_name
FROM (`posts`)
JOIN `categories` ON `posts`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`
WHERE `category_id` IS NULL
ORDER BY `id` desc
LIMIT 20
```

====

EDIT 2:

So I found some mistakes in the code and fixed them, tried again, but still I get an error: (The mistakes were using `$categoryID` instead of `$categoryId` and select `category.name` instead of the true name of the table `categories` which is `categories.name`

```
Error Number: 1052: Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous
SELECT *, `categories`.`name` AS category_name
FROM (`posts`)
JOIN `categories` ON `posts`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`
WHERE `category_id` =  '3'
ORDER BY `id` desc
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I don't get any, just got a normal response. I want to add another column called `category_name` that will hold the name from `categories.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
function getPostsWithByCategoryID($numberOfRows, $start, $categoryId)
{
    $this->db->select('*, categories.name AS category_name');
    $this->db->from('posts')->order_by('posts.id','desc')->limit($numberOfRows, $start);
    $this->db->where('category_id', $categoryId);
    $this->db->join('categories', 'posts.category_id = categories.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: I missspelled catagory.name should be categories.name, I updated my answer

Comment: Since both tables has an ID you need to specify which to order by in order_by like so: 'posts.id'

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
$this->db->select('*');
```

by

```
$this->db->select('posts.*');
$this->db->select('categories.name','category_name');
```

CI's documentation is pretty good.

Comment: I still get the same result... I think that it have to be something that tells the table to add a new column with the selected categories.name?

Comment: in your join statement instead of == put =

Comment: and is your join query working?. $this->db->select('categories.name','category_name');
means it gets name and assigns it to category_name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this I think you forget to place = in place of ==

```
function getPostsWithByCategoryID($numberOfRows, $start, $categoryId)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('posts')->order_by('id','desc')->limit($numberOfRows, $start);
    $this->db->where('category_id', $categoryID);
    $this->db->join('categories', 'posts.category_id = categories.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Still the same result..\

Comment: Do you want an alias for column name?